# Javascript Else If Statement is not evaluating second condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm making a medical calculator and am wondering why the first "else if" statement is not being evaluated. - What I'm trying to do is calculate "if the initialPTT is less than or equal to 40 AND the bodyweight is over 250, then display "1000 Maximum Dose Reached."  It seems to be just doing the calculation on line on the first "if" statement and the first "else if" statement.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate()
{
  bodyWeight = document.getElementById("bodyWeight").value;
  initialPTT = document.getElementById("initialPTT").value;

  document.getElementById("resultInfusionUnitsHr").innerHTML = bodyWeight * initialPTT;

  // Start Infusion Units/Hr
  if(initialPTT <= 40){
    document.getElementById("resultInfusionUnitsHr").innerHTML = bodyWeight * 4;
  } else if ((initialPTT <=40) && (bodyWeight > 250)){
    document.getElementById("resultInfusionUnitsHr").innerHTML = "1000 Maximum Dose Reached"; 
  } else if ((initialPTT <=40) && (initialPTT < 51)){
    document.getElementById("resultInfusionUnitsHr").innerHTML = bodyWeight * 2;  
  } else if ((initialPTT <=40) && (initialPTT < 51) && (bodyWeight > 500)){
    document.getElementById("resultInfusionUnitsHr").innerHTML = "1000 Maximum Dose Reached";  
  } else {
    document.getElementById("resultInfusionUnitsHr").innerHTML = bodyWeight * 2;
  }

}
```

[See it on CodePen](https://codepen.io/chai714/pen/jxJEOJ)

Comment: "_if the initialPTT is greater than or equal_". Greater or equal is `>=` not `<=`. But checking for equal is not going to work anyway because in that case it will enter the first if.

Comment: Because anything that matches the condition for each of your `else if` will have already been matched by the `if` statement. Use `if` for each clause if you want all of the conditions to be checked regardless of what previous ones matched.

Comment: Try this. State clearly, in simple words, what you think an `if` statement does. If you're confused, you could try reading the documentation. Then state clearly in simple words, what you think your logic does. Hint: `else` means "else", not "and also if".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your condition to this

```
// Start Infusion Units/Hr
if ((initialPTT <= 40) && (bodyWeight <= 250)) { 
  document.getElementById("resultInfusionUnitsHr").innerHTML = bodyWeight * 4;
} else if ((initialPTT <= 40) && (bodyWeight > 250)) {
  resultInfusionUnitsHr = "1000 Maximum Dose Reached";
} else if ((initialPTT <= 40) && (initialPTT < 51) && (bodyWeight < 500)) {
  document.getElementById("resultInfusionUnitsHr").innerHTML = bodyWeight * 2;
} else if ((initialPTT <= 40) && (initialPTT < 51) && (bodyWeight > 500)) {
  document.getElementById("resultInfusionUnitsHr").innerHTML = "1000 Maximum Dose Reached";
} else {
  document.getElementById("resultInfusionUnitsHr").innerHTML = bodyWeight * 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Saeed!  This did the trick. I didn't think of adding criteria to the first statement.

Comment: Your welcome, Good luck. You can accept the answer if it helps @Chai

Comment: Why DV? please explain.

Answer (score 0):

the way that if statements and if else and else statements work is, first the if statement is evaluated, if false, moves on to next else if and so on until it gets to the else statement, which runs if all if and if else statements were evaluated as false. However, soon as one of the if statements is evaluated true, the block of code following that if statement is ran, then the other if statements are **not** run.

let's look at this example:

```
//given two variables a and b
if (a === true && b === true){
    // case 1
} else if (a === true && b === false){
    // case 2
} else if (a === false && b === true){
    // case 3
} else {
    // case 4
}
//soon as **any one of** the four cases above is run, the next line to run is the one that would be here, the if statements only get evaluated until the first one to be evaluated true.
```

so, in your code, only the if and else statements could possibly run. none of the else if statements could possibly run because they all require initialPPT <= 40. but if that was the case, the if statement would be the one to run. what you want to do is nest if statements.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation rakan316.  Appreciate this.